# Creating matrix from data frame R

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to recreate a matrix from this data frame

```
head(INDEX)

       RLonINT RLatINT   mean 
1         1       1      -1.8  
9901      2       1      -1.8  
19801     3       1      -1.7  
29702     4       1      -1.8  
39602     5       1      -2.0  
49505     6       1      -1.9
```

where `length(INDEX$mean) = 2592` and eventually I would like a `72x36` matrix

Many thanks

Comment: is `RLonINT` from 1 to 72 and `RLatInt` from 1 to 36? If those are latitude and longitude would you rather have a spatial raster?

Comment: @Spacedman yes RLonINT[1:72] and RLatINT[1:36]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an empty matrix of the right size:

```
> m = matrix(NA, 72, 36)
```

then assigning using a 2-column matrix of (i,j) values works like this:

```
> m[as.matrix(INDEX[,1:2])] = INDEX$mean
```